# How do publish end remote events work

Tags: publishing, performance-optimization, publishing-targets

We have different CM and CD servers

I am generating files on `publish:end` and `publish:end:remote` events. Files will be generated in the website-Root/Dictionary Folder.

What files? - We are going through each sites dictionary folder and creating JSON files with dictionary key value pairs.

I am clear on how its generating files on the Content Management server Data folder. As the publish event happened on this server. We are not really worried about performance impact on CM server.

what i am not clear is how the content delivery network is picking up this publish event (may be some how `publish:end:remote` event is letting the CD server know) and generating these files?

Is there going to be any performance impact on the content delivery server?

Comment: Not really an answer, but rather than generating static files from CMS content why don't you just use the CMS and a special layout to generate the output like all your other content. You can use the CMS component cache to make it go very fast if you need that, and it's already wired into the publish process.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When `publish:end:remote` event is raised, there is an entry created in the core database `EventQueue` table.

All the servers (including CD servers) check that table and executes all the handlers.

In terms of performance impact, it all depends on the code which generates the files.

Comment: So, it does mean the same code run on CD server to generate files again. is it better to generate files only on publish:end and on publish:end:remote write code which get those files from CM server and replaces into CD server?

Comment: That would be an option. It depends whether this code is using lot of CPU. Maybe it's not worth it

Answer (score 14):

The communication between the Content Delivery and Content Management box is handled through the Event Queue.

1. Your Content Management instance triggers an event (i.e.: "publish:end:remote")
2. This event is added to the EventQueue table in the database that is targeted by the event. for the "publish:end:remote" event is usually the "web" database unless you've specified custom publishing targets/databases
3. Every 2 seconds, your CD instance poll the EventQueue table in the database where they retrieve content. If they find an event queued up in the EventQueue table, they attemp to handle it through the handler for the "website" site.

The interval at which you Content Delivery instance poll the EventQueue is configurable in the `sitecore.config` file under the `/sitecore/eventQueue/processingInterval` node

Comment: do you know why "publish:complete:remote" is placed in the `core` database and the "publish:end:remote" is placed in the `web` database? Also, is it possible to control which database a specific event goes into? I have 2 CDs and one of them does not have access to the same `core` database as the CM (it's in a different region), so it never sees the event.